# Conexion SQL Server wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, apache

Tengo un problema con un sitio que se realizó en wordpress versión 5.9. La cual estaba conectada a una base de datos SQL Server y en este momento migrado la base de datos SQL Server a MYSQL pero al momento de desplegarme dice que necesito esta extensión SQLSrv, el tema es que esta extensión pertence a la conexion con SQL Servidor. ¿Cómo hago para que no me pida esta extensión y pueda conectarme con MYSQL? Dato curioso si creo una conexión con un worpress nuevo si se enlaza directamente con MYSQL.

Herramientas con las que estoy realizando el uso de PHP 8.1, Apache2, Linux Centos 7, Mysql 8.

Lo que realice fue una migración desde SQL server a MYSQL lo cual quedo bien, utilice el mismo proyecto wordpress cambiando los datos del config.php para suministrar los datos de conexión a la base de datos. Lo intentó tanto en Windows como en Linux.

Comment: Sí te sale eso es porque en algún punto de tu programa está intentando usar código basado en el controlador de SQL Server. Debes identificar dónde ocurre eso y cambiarlo por código basado en Mysqli o PDO.

Comment: gracias por su respuesta, tiene razón, tal vez podría darme un tip para revisar en el código como en que clase debo hacerlo, disculpeme le agradeceria.

Comment: Debería ser una clase donde se definen los parámetros de la conexión. Generalmente el nombre es intuitivo.

Comment: Revisa el log de errores o activa temporalmente el modo de debug de WordPress para saber dónde está ocurriendo el problema exactamente.

Comment: Busca en todo el código el mensaje de error. Yo lo pondría en wp-contents/mu_plugins